# filtering data from one list to another using an array but in two different ways

Tags: javascript, arrays

Goal is to filter out data using the array `selected_bank_ids` which will contain the bank `id` and/or the last 3 digits for `401` accounts.

One issue I have is removing an entire row of `bank_data` that contains the digit string "401" within `selected_bank_ids`

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

```js
bank_data = [{"arrival_time":"12:00","amount":"900","id":"BS"},  
{"arrival_time" :"12:00",  "amount":"300",    "id":"BD"      },
{"arrival_time" :"01:00",  "amount":"400",    "id":"SW"      },
{"arrival_time" :"02:00",  "amount":"800",    "id":"OS-401"  },
{"arrival_time" :"03:00",  "amount":"500",    "id":"SF"      },
{"arrival_time" :"04:00",  "amount":"600",    "id":"SJ"      },
{"arrival_time" :"04:30",  "amount":"700",    "id":"SJ"      },
{"arrival_time" :undefined,"amount":undefined,"id":undefined },
{"arrival_time" :"04:00",  "amount":"600",    "id":"FS-401"  },
{"arrival_time" :"05:00",  "amount":"600",    "id":"FS"      },
{"arrival_time" :"06:00",  "amount":"900",    "id":"JC"      }];

upcoming_bank_data = []; 

//Goal is to grab any item within bank_id list or ids that end in 401
selected_bank_ids = ['BS','BD','SJ', 'FS', '401'];

for(i in selected_bank_ids) { 
    is_401 = false;
    bank_data = bank_data.filter((item) =>{ 
        
    if(item.id != undefined) {
        parser = selected_bank_ids[i].substring(selected_bank_ids[i].length - 3);
        //would make sure that bank_id would always include 401 towards the end
        is_401 = item.id.includes(parser);
    }
        
    if (item.id === selected_bank_ids[i] || is_401) {
        upcoming_bank_data.push(item);
        is_401 = false;
    }
    
    return item.id !== selected_bank_ids[i];
    });
}

/*
console.log('upcoming_bank_data');
console.log(upcoming_bank_data);
console.log('-----------------------');
console.log('bank_data');
console.log(bank_data);
*/
```

**Current result**

- `bank_data` should not contain a row that has the string digit 401 within the id

```js
upcoming_bank_data
[ { arrival_time: '12:00', amount: '900', id: 'BS' },
  { arrival_time: '12:00', amount: '300', id: 'BD' },
  { arrival_time: '04:00', amount: '600', id: 'SJ' },
  { arrival_time: '04:30', amount: '700', id: 'SJ' },
  { arrival_time: '04:00', amount: '600', id: 'FS-401' },
  { arrival_time: '05:00', amount: '600', id: 'FS' },
  { arrival_time: '02:00', amount: '800', id: 'OS-401' },
  { arrival_time: '04:00', amount: '600', id: 'FS-401' } ]
-----------------------
bank_data
[ { arrival_time: '01:00', amount: '400', id: 'SW' },
  { arrival_time: '02:00', amount: '800', id: 'OS-401' },
  { arrival_time: '03:00', amount: '500', id: 'SF' },
  { arrival_time: undefined, amount: undefined, id: undefined },
  { arrival_time: '04:00', amount: '600', id: 'FS-401' },
  { arrival_time: '06:00', amount: '900', id: 'JC' } ]
```

**Desired result**

```js
upcoming_bank_data
[ { arrival_time: '12:00', amount: '900', id: 'BS' },
  { arrival_time: '12:00', amount: '300', id: 'BD' },
  { arrival_time: '02:00', amount: '800', id: 'OS-401' },
  { arrival_time: '04:00', amount: '600', id: 'SJ' },
  { arrival_time: '04:30', amount: '700', id: 'SJ' },
  { arrival_time: '04:00', amount: '600', id: 'FS-401' },
  { arrival_time: '05:00', amount: '600', id: 'FS' }]
-----------------------
bank_data
[ { arrival_time: '01:00', amount: '400', id: 'SW' },
  { arrival_time: '03:00', amount: '500', id: 'SF' },
  { arrival_time: undefined, amount: undefined, id: undefined },
  { arrival_time: '06:00', amount: '900', id: 'JC' } ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reduce the array and take a partition for `a` and `b`.

```js
const
    bank_data = [{ arrival_time: "12:00", amount: "900", id: "BS" }, { arrival_time: "12:00", amount: "300", id: "BD" }, { arrival_time: "01:00", amount: "400", id: "SW" }, { arrival_time: "02:00", amount: "800", id: "OS-401" }, { arrival_time: "03:00", amount: "500", id: "SF" }, { arrival_time: "04:00", amount: "600", id: "SJ" }, { arrival_time: "04:30", amount: "700", id: "SJ" }, { arrival_time: undefined, amount: undefined, id: undefined }, { arrival_time: "04:00", amount: "600", id: "FS-401" }, { arrival_time: "05:00", amount: "600", id: "FS" }, { arrival_time: "06:00", amount: "900", id: "JC" }],
    selected_bank_ids = ['BS','BD','SJ', 'FS', '401'],
    [a, b] = bank_data.reduce((r, o) => {
        const check = selected_bank_ids.includes(o.id) || (o.id || '').slice(-3) === '401';
        r[+check].push(o);
        return r;
    }, [[], []]);
 
 console.log(b);
 console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for might be just one line of code

```js
bank_data = [{ arrival_time: '01:00', amount: '400', id: 'SW' },
    { arrival_time: '02:00', amount: '800', id: 'OS-401' },
    { arrival_time: '03:00', amount: '500', id: 'SF' },
    { arrival_time: undefined, amount: undefined, id: undefined },
    { arrival_time: '04:00', amount: '600', id: 'FS-401' },
    { arrival_time: '06:00', amount: '900', id: 'JC' }];


const filtered_bank_data = bank_data.filter(e => !e.id || !e.id.endsWith('401'))

console.log(filtered_bank_data);
```

So, you are filtering all elements in the bank_data array which doesn't have id (it's undefined) or which id doesn't end with 401

Answer (score 0):

Another way to filter the array excluding ids with 401 at the end:

```js
const upcomingBankData = [{ arrival_time: '01:00', amount: '400', id: 'SW' }, { arrival_time: '02:00', amount: '800', id: 'OS-401' }, { arrival_time: '03:00', amount: '500', id: 'SF' }, { arrival_time: undefined, amount: undefined, id: undefined }, { arrival_time: '04:00', amount: '600', id: 'FS-401' }, { arrival_time: '06:00', amount: '900', id: 'JC' }]

const bankData = upcomingBankData.filter(a => !/401$/.test(a.id))

console.log(bankData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a simple way by iterating the input array and via use of `String.includes()` & `Array.includes()`.

**Working Demo :**

```js
// Input Data
const bank_data = [{"arrival_time":"12:00","amount":"900","id":"BS"},  
{"arrival_time" :"12:00",  "amount":"300",    "id":"BD"      },
{"arrival_time" :"01:00",  "amount":"400",    "id":"SW"      },
{"arrival_time" :"02:00",  "amount":"800",    "id":"OS-401"  },
{"arrival_time" :"03:00",  "amount":"500",    "id":"SF"      },
{"arrival_time" :"04:00",  "amount":"600",    "id":"SJ"      },
{"arrival_time" :"04:30",  "amount":"700",    "id":"SJ"      },
{"arrival_time" :undefined,"amount":undefined,"id":undefined },
{"arrival_time" :"04:00",  "amount":"600",    "id":"FS-401"  },
{"arrival_time" :"05:00",  "amount":"600",    "id":"FS"      },
{"arrival_time" :"06:00",  "amount":"900",    "id":"JC"      }];

const selected_bank_ids = ['BS','BD','SJ', 'FS', '401'];

// Result : Filtered data
const res = bank_data.filter((obj) => {
    return (obj.id?.includes('-')) ?
    selected_bank_ids.includes(obj.id.split('-')[1]) :
    selected_bank_ids.includes(obj.id)
});

console.log(res);
```